# Plotting geo-data using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Can somebody tell how to plot given latitude and longitude data in the Spark dataframe, how to plot them on the world map?

Answer (score 4):

Spark can not create plots, it's a computing framework. But there are tools which help to visualize data stored in spark's dataframes. For plotting, you must of course collect all the data you want to visualize to the driver node.

We use spark-notebook (https://github.com/spark-notebook/spark-notebook) , which has several options to visualize data (plot.ly, leaflet etc). Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]